# How to handle UIWebView cases were no connection, and should I use Network indicator?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

What´s the preferred way of handling an app that an integral part of it is using UIWebView, the first view the user sees when app is first loaded is a UIWebView trying to access a webpage... If the connection is slow or if there is no connection at all - how should I handle this?

also, does UIWebView require you to use the network indicator (spinner) when it´s using the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always try to provide feedback to the user, it helps in increasing usability. So, yes spinners(activity and network indicators) are very useful. You might also learn a lot by looking at other apps as to how they handle network errors. Facebook for example shows a nice message saying "Network Unreachable, Try again". You can implement actions like this which will always let the user know how to proceed.

As to handling network connection, Apple provides Reachability class. Look at the attached example to understand how to implement this - 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use `activityindicator` to show loading....

and then stop `indicator` in `UIWebView` `delegate` method

```
  -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```